# Does this sentence sound awkward?

Tags: formality

"Unlike my specific ancestry, he is a biracial individual with roots in Asia and in U.S."

I'm having trouble especially in the first section, where I am trying to show that my friend's background is different from mine. I also have to be formal, and not use any conversational language.
Any suggestions to make this a clearer and better sentence?

Thanks!

Comment: You might find it useful to read this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier) about *dangling modifiers* (and/or you could look up that term using this site's search box for other postings on the subject).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sentence sounds awkward.

As Erik Kowal has pointed out, the sentence suffers from a dangling modifier (no, that's not something that afflicts aging men). More specifically, in the construction

> **Unlike** X, Y...

you are contrasting X and Y. Thus your sentence contrasts "my specific ancestry" and "he." That's dang dangly.

Besides that problem, you've presented a very specific description of your friend's background with a non-description of your background. "Specific ancestry" is a clunky collocation, and all that you're suggesting is that you are *not* "a biracial individual with roots in Asia and in U.S." (which should be changed to "the U.S."). So if you're trying to present an effective contrast, it may be better to truly get specific about your ancestry, rather than just referring to it as "specific," which does not help the reader too much.

In this situation, "unlike" is not the optimal choice of contrasting expression. I would suggest **while** or **whereas**.

For example:

> **While** my ancestors are from Europe, he is a biracial individual with roots in Asia and the U.S.
>
> **Whereas** my ancestry is primarily Scottish, he is a biracial individual with roots in Asia and the U.S.

Still, I think there's a problem with the "biracial" part of your statement, since "ancestry" and "race" are not always tied so neatly at the hip, and having "roots in the U.S." does not clearly denote a particular race (how deep must roots be to be called roots?). But that's best addressed with another question, one that is sure to be popular.

Comment: "Whereas my ancestry is primarily Canadian, he is a biracial individual with roots in Asia and in the U.S."

Is this alright? I mean, I still do not know how to edit "ancestry" "race" and "roots" ..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix would be to drop the "unlike" clause, unless the comparison with yourself is important (eg emphasizing that this person can supply insights which you're admitting you lack so you make a good team).

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence (though clumsy) is clear as it is.  If this is a letter of recommendation, I would suggest that you do not emphasize his heritage so much. It can be mentioned together with his other characteristics. e.g. He is an Asian American with a college degree in ...., etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this expression : He does not have only one race as i have.

Comment: Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise, it's likely to be viewed as only opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.